# current_page? inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

Is there any easy way of using something like `current_page?`method
from `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` inside controller?

I have routing like:

```
resources :addresses
resources :mailing_addresses, :controller => 'addresses'
```

And I would like to do a check in my controller that would look like
this:

```
class AddressesController

  def index
    if current_page?(live_addresses_path)
       # ... logic goes here
    elsif current_page?(addresses_path)
       # ... logic goes here
    end
  end

end
```

What's the easiest way of achieving it?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url this way you can do `request.original_url` or `request.original_fullpath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike many other helper methods, `UrlHelper` is not included in your controllers. So, if you want to use it in your controller, you can simply include it there and use it:

```
class AddressesController

  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def index
    if current_page?(live_addresses_path)
       # ... logic goes here
    elsif current_page?(addresses_path)
       # ... logic goes here
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but having another error now: `arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation`. I tried to add routes like `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` but still nothing :(

Comment: Are you passing strings to `current_page?` as in your example code or some other arguments?